# Show discount price on changing product quantity - Woocommerce Dynamic Pricing plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce Dynamic Pricing plugin and facing issue to show discounted price on product detail page.

I have 3 user roles and set pricing rules with minimum and maximum product quantity on fixed price. When I am logged in with that specific role (stockist), it's not showing me the discount price.

If I add that product to the cart then it shows me discounted price in cart.

Is there a way I can change the price on changing product quantity.

I have pricing rule as:

```
1) product quantity is in between 4-16 price is $40
2) product quantity is in between 17-50 price is $39
3) product quantity is in between 51 and more price is $35
```

I found a code but that is not working with dynamic pricing rules:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_total_product_price', 31 );
function woocommerce_total_product_price() {
    global $woocommerce, $product;
    // let's setup our divs
    echo sprintf('<div id="product_total_price" style="margin-bottom:20px;display:none">%s %s</div>',__('Product Total:','woocommerce'),'<span class="price">'.$product->get_price().'</span>');
    echo sprintf('<div id="cart_total_price" style="margin-bottom:20px;display:none">%s %s</div>',__('Cart Total:','woocommerce'),'<span class="price">'.$product->get_price().'</span>');
    ?>
        <script>
            jQuery(function($){
                var price = <?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>,
                    current_cart_total = <?php echo $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total; ?>,
                    currency = '<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?>';

                $('[name=quantity]').change(function(){
                    if (!(this.value < 1)) {
                        var product_total = parseFloat(price * this.value),
                        cart_total = parseFloat(product_total + current_cart_total);

                        $('#product_total_price .price').html( currency + product_total.toFixed(2));
                        $('#cart_total_price .price').html( currency + cart_total.toFixed(2));
                    }
                    $('#product_total_price,#cart_total_price').toggle(!(this.value <= 1));

                });
            });
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

Can anyone suggest me a way to do that.

Thanks

Comment: if you are using [this plugin](https://woocommerce.com/products/dynamic-pricing/), it will not work. the pricing is calculated on cart and cannot be calculated on product page.

Comment: Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I'm an author of a [plugin](http://reigelgallarde.me/doc/woocommerce-product-price-x-quantity-preview/) that does exactly what you want but have not found any solution. But my plugin works with this one,
 [WooCommerce Dynamic Pricing & Discounts](https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-dynamic-pricing-discounts/7119279)

Comment: @Reigel Thanks for your response. I can't spend more $29 as i already purchase dynamic pricing of $129.. Is there any other way, any custom code, that allow me to do the required functionality.

Comment: @Thomas, as for me it's most requested by the users of my plugin. I have tried but have not found a solution as well. The main problem is that its pricing is calculated on the cart. By that you should add the product first to the cart to get the dynamic price.

Comment: @Reigel Thanks for your help.. I will try to find out a way for that.

Comment: let us know what you find. I would love a solution for this too.